# Why is my real-valued spherical harmonic representation inaccurate?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I wrote a simple class in Python to compute spherical harmonic basis functions and corresponding coefficients for a function defined on a sphere. See below.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import sph_harm
import scipy.integrate as integrate

class SphHarmBasis():
    def __init__(self, n_coeffs=16):
        self._n_coeffs = n_coeffs
        self.basis = self.sph_harm_basis()
        
    ''' Compute real spherical harmonic basis function '''
    
    def get_sph_harm_function(self, l, m):
        def basis_function(theta, phi):
            Y = sph_harm(abs(m), l, phi, theta)
            
            if m < 0:
                Y = np.sqrt(2) * (-1)**m * Y.imag
            elif m > 0:
                Y = np.sqrt(2) * (-1)**m * Y.real
                
            return Y.real
        
        return basis_function
    
    ''' Get a specified number of basis functions '''

    def sph_harm_basis(self):
        basis_functions = []

        dimension = 0
        l, m = 0, 0

        while dimension < self._n_coeffs:
            while m <= l:
                basis_functions.append(self.get_sph_harm_function(l, m))
                m += 1
                dimension += 1
            
            l += 1
            m = -l  
        
        return basis_functions
    
    ''' Compute spherical harmonic coefficients ''' 

    def sph_harm_coeff(self, Y, f):
        def integrand(phi, theta):
            return f(theta, phi) * Y(theta, phi) * np.sin(theta)
        
        return integrate.dblquad(integrand, 0., np.pi, lambda x : 0., lambda x : 2*np.pi)[0]
    
    ''' Get spherical harmonic coefficients for a function in a basis '''

    def sph_harm_transform(self, f, basis=None):
        if basis is None:
            basis = self.basis
        
        coeffs = []

        for Y in basis:
            coeffs.append(self.sph_harm_coeff(Y, f))

        return coeffs
    
    ''' Reconstruct a function from basis and corresponding coefficients'''

    def sph_harm_reconstruct(self, coeffs, basis=None):
        if basis is None:
            basis = self.basis
        
        return lambda theta, phi : np.dot(coeffs, [f(theta, phi) for f in basis])
```

And you can use it like this:

```
def my_sphere_function(theta, phi):
    return np.sin(theta+phi)

my_basis = SphHarmBasis(n_coeffs=25)

# encode your function in the desired basis and record the coefficients
my_coeffs = my_basis.sph_harm_transform(my_sphere_function)

# reconstruct your function at a point
point = (np.pi, np.pi/8)
my_basis.sph_harm_reconstruct(my_coeffs)(*point), my_sphere_function(*point)
```

My problem is that it doesn't seem to be very accurate.

For example, running the follow test code reports a mean absolute error of `0.4933463836715332`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_reconstr_function = my_basis.sph_harm_reconstruct(my_coeffs)

pts = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
pts_2d = np.reshape(np.stack(np.meshgrid(pts,pts), axis=-1), (-1, 2))

actual = []
approx = []

pts_total = 0

for n, pt in enumerate(pts_2d):
    f_actual = my_sphere_function(*pt)
    f_approx = my_reconstr_function(*pt)
    
    actual.append(f_actual)
    approx.append(f_approx)

    pts_total += abs(f_approx - f_actual)
    
print(pts_total / len(pts_2d))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(np.reshape(np.repeat(actual, 3), (50, 50, 3)))

plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(np.reshape(np.repeat(approx, 3), (50, 50, 3)))
```

[Actual vs. reconstructed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLQ8M.png)

On the left is an image representation of the actual function, and on the right is the reconstructed function.

Where is my error? Changing the number of coefficients doesn't seem to affect much.

Comment: Not sure, but reconstructed image looks like actual, but shifted on a grid. Also, the gap between light areas in reconstructed also points in the wrong-grid direction.

Comment: From the picture, it looks like there is a difference in how angles are defined, 0 to 2 pi versus minus pi to plus pi or something like that. Also maybe a mirror image, angle A versus pi minus A. Maybe try all values of l and m, l = 0, 1, 2, ..., m = 0, 1, 2, ... . The first few functions should be very simple so maybe it's easier to see if they're right. By the way, this is a great problem, well worth solving, but are you sure you need to? Maybe you can use a function from a library for your purposes. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for the hint about the angles--my test code was the issue. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was testing samples out of the domain of the spherical harmonic basis functions. I specified the correct integration bounds, as the polar angle must be in the interval `[0, pi]` while the azimuthal belongs to `[0, 2pi]`. But for my test example, `pts_2d` was in the interval `[0, 2pi]^2`. All is well!

[Reconstruction comparison after fixing the test code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD7EK.png)